# Bootstrap.js file in both parent and iframe

Tags: javascript, web, twitter-bootstrap, javascript-framework

I am creating a web app using bootstrap by twitter. The app contains of a page which loads up another page of the same domain in an iframe. Now my problem is, if the page that I am loading in iframe also contains bootstrap.js file it starts conflicting with the app.
For example, my app has a accordion (collapse) http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse built using the data attributes.
Once a page with bootstrap.js is loaded the collapse event starts getting fired twice.So something like

```
<head>//Bootstrap css and js files included</head>
<body>
   <div>
     //Collapsible Menu #1
   </div>
   <iframe>
       <head>
           //BootStrap.js script from same location as parent
       </head>
       <body>
           // Another Collapsible Menu #2
       </body>
    `  </head> 
   </iframe>
</body>
```

Here when I try to click on Menu #1, the code of Bootstrap.js gets triggered twice which ends ups in showing and then hiding the menu.
But my problem is not just limited to the menu. I need to be able to use bootstrap.js in my app and also allow pages which already contain bootstrap.js to be loaded inside the iframe.

Is there a way around this or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The iframe should pose no problem (an example [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/wxeY7/) works for me). Are you perhaps loading both **bootstrap.js** and **bootstrap-collapse.js**?  That would cause this behavior. Also, does Menu #2 exhibit the same behavior? - you only mentioned #1.

Comment: I had the same issue too but didn't have the time to solve the problem. However, I fixed it by creating another custom bootstrap, unchecking the "Grid System" and "Responsive Utilities" options and downloading. I would use this new minified css exclusively in the iframes. It seems taking away the media queries fixes this issue, but it is not the most ideal solution.

Comment: I actually found the problem.. it was very specific for my app. The way it was working was - there was an included JS file to trigger the app inside the "target" webpage. The JS file would not remove everything from the page and build an iframe to put load the content of the "target" inside iframe. Now in this case, I had BootstrapJS running before the app.js file which in turn resulted in getting executed in the "parent" frame and then when the app loads it was getting reloaded causing the conflict (or multiple events due to multiple inclusion).. Good thing I learned a lot since then! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the problem.. it was very specific for my app. The way it was working was - there was an included JS file to trigger the app inside the "target" webpage. The JS file would not remove everything from the page and build an iframe to put load the content of the "target" inside iframe. Now in this case, I had BootstrapJS running before the app.js file which in turn resulted in getting executed in the "parent" frame and then when the app loads it was getting reloaded causing the conflict (or multiple events due to multiple inclusion).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in IE9 only.

I was opening an instance of my website in an IFRAME dialog. Meaning that there was 2 instances of Bootstrap, like above.

When I moused out of the IFRAME it resized the underlying layout to match that of the width of the smaller one in the IFRAME.

To get round it I had to disable the opening pages bootstrap-responsive.js stylesheet using javascript. You can then turn it back on, when you close the IFRAME dialog.

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident/5")>-1){
    window.parent.document.getElementById("responsiveCSS").sheet.disabled = true;
}
```

Horrible hack, I know.

Comment: I can't do that... My iframe page and parent page both need bootstrap enabled all the time... The parent page lets the user edit few things on the child page... so basically, both iframe and parent window are open all the time..